# jQuery - Remove self-closing tags in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, replace, kentico

I am working on a navigation for a site that is composed of several jQuery accordions containing lists of links, like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <h3>Header 1</h3>
        <ul>
            <li class="menuItem">Link 1</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Link 2</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Header 2</h3>
        <ul>
            <li class="menuItem">Link 4</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Link 5</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Link 6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CMS that the site is built on, for some reason, sets any empty lists as self-closing `<li>` tags, like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <h3>Header 1</h3>
        <ul>
            <li class="menuItem">Link 1</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Link 2</li>
            <li class="menuItem">Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li />
</ul>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to find and remove all `<li />` tags from the HTML using jQuery. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, this only shows up in IE7. In IE8/9, the browser has `<li></li>` in the HTML, but it doesn't render these tags as anything. The `<li />` tag affects the layout in IE7 (it looks like it's being rendered as a block element, so it's pushing the content below it down).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, none of the fixes worked in IE6, though they did work in all other browsers. To get everything working in IE6, I added a class to the `<li>`'s and used `$('#xyz').remove();` in the body to get rid of the tags.

Answer (score 6):

`$('li:empty')` will find all empty `<li>` tags. Then `.remove()` should nuke them.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("li:empty").remove();
```

[Documentation on `:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)